# Clients get disconnected automatically

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to implement a chat module for my app and getting 2 problems.

The first one is that my clients in sockets keep on disconnecting automatically.
Here's what I am doing.

My clients get connected in a room which is dynamically created and the name of the room is a random ID that i generate.Now when a client sends a message I print a log to see how many people are there in the room and it logs "2" on the server side which is correct.But when I keep on sending messages from the clients to the server it start showing me "1" client is connected and after some time it shows me 0 clients are connected in the room.The people are automatically disconnecting why is this happening?

```
socket.on('SendChat',function(msgobj){      //pass the message to all people in the room.
console.log("Msg from" + msgobj.MsgSenderName + " in RoomID = "+ msgobj.RoomID);
console.log("People in room " +io.sockets.clients(msgobj.RoomID).length);
    socket.broadcast.to(String(msgobj.RoomID)).emit('RecieveChat',msgobj);  
});
```

This event is raised on the server side when someone sends a message from any of the client and the `msgobj` will contain the RoomID.So you can see I am logging number of people in the room.

The second problem is I am trying to broadcast the message which I recieve from a client.But the event at the other client is not raised.In the above code you can see the last line I used to broadcast msg to all the other clients but the events at those clients is not fired I don't know why.Here's what is on my client

```
this.Socket.on('RecieveChat',function(obj){
    self.Controller.RecieveChat(obj);
});
```

and here's my log

[image]
You can see the `RoomID` is same but the people in room are leaving and this snapshot is only showing `1 people in room` before that there were two people in room which then cut of to 1 and eventually 0.

**EDIT:**

When I change `socket.broadcast.to(String(msgobj.RoomID)).emit('RecieveChat',msgobj);` to `socket.broadcast.emit('RecieveChat',msgobj);` it starts working but not working if I emit inside a `room` using the `to` method.

`Transport end (close timeout)` this seems to be causing the issue.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564633/node-js-sockets-io-disconnecting-every-25-seconds-heartbeat-related) the problem was with the version of socket.io that I was using.